# Changing iterm2 Terminal Color

Tags: terminal, iterm

Is there a way to bold the color of the current active terminal tab in iterm2? I do not see an option to do that on the appearance tab of preferences. I know I can change the tab style, but I still want a really bold appearance.

[image: active terminal tab]

From the above picture, I want the middle tab to be of a bold color (orange or some other bright colors) when it is active.

Answer (score 2):

iTerm2 build 2.1.4 on OS X 10.11.4 has that capability built in:

View > Tab Colour:

[image: View>Tab Colour menu]

Clicking one of the colours has the following result (Inactive):
[image: inactive iTerm2 tab]

(Active)
[image: active iTerm2 tab]